# Compare object with string in django template

Tags: python, django, object, templates

I have two models which I want to output on a template. But only if the parent class object matches to the child class object.

```
         {% for market in markets %}

          {% if object.market|slugify == market.market %}
             >>> DO SOMETHING <<<
          {% endif %}

         {% endfor %}
```

The problem is when I use slugify on the Object it's giving me a string which starts with a small letter but market.market outputs a string with a capital letter.
Do someone know a solid solution for that?

UPDATE:

my Views:

```
class ItemDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Item
    template_name = "product.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ItemDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['markets'] = Market.objects.all()
        # And so on for more models
        return context

def market_list(request):
    context ={
        'markets': Market.objects.all()
    }

    return render(request, "market-list.html", context)
```

My Models:

```
class Market(models.Model):
    market = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    branch = models.CharField(choices=BRANCH_CHOICES, max_length=1)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.market

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("core:market-product-list", kwargs={
        'slug': self.slug
    })

class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    market = models.ForeignKey(Market, related_name='children', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField()
    discount_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(ItemCategory, related_name='children', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    label = models.CharField(choices=LABEL_CHOICES, max_length=1)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Please *don't* filter in the template. Normally you also use a `ForeignKey` to refer to another model object.

Comment: market.market is the foreign key argument in my object.  I managed to output the child class with "   {% if object.market|slugify|capfirst == market.market %}"

Comment: then it makes no sense to compare it that way, then you can simply work with `object.market == market`. But regardless, it makes no sense to do this in the template, since templates are inefficient, and it result in a large amount of data transfers from the database to the Python/Django level.

Comment: big thanks !! I am new to django and could not see the easiest way get things working. Just changed it to object.market == market :)

Comment: but that still is not efficient. Can you share the relevant models (the models of the `object` and `market`, and your view)?

Comment: I am glad about every hint, just updated the post with my models and views.